# How is the message 'Please avoid extended discussions in comments' triggered?

Tags: support, comments, chat

Is it triggered after a number of comments within a short time frame, or is there a moderator button you have to click on?

Comment: Related: [Where's the auto-move-to-chat link?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10691) (answered by a member of staff)

Comment: You might want to change the accepted answer on this question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no human (or moderator) involvement.

It's purely automatic.

I'm not 100% of the exact criteria but I believe it's triggered after a number of comments from two users which would indicate they were holding a conversation.

Comment: If you're not sure, then why not leave a comment rather than answer?

Comment: @user1271772 you see that this has been answered almost 4 years ago, right?

Comment: It was answered 11 days ago.

Comment: @user1271772 if you check this answer it reads jan 28, 2018.

Comment: My question was to ChrisF. I felt it was a low-quality post. In my opinion the question got answered by Catija recently. I'll let you say the last word if you want it. Comments are not meant for extended discussion.

Answer (score 17):

I had the opportunity to answer a similar question on the [Code Review meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10691/wheres-the-auto-move-to-chat-link/10692#10692) a while back and got one of the devs to look up how we do this - the rules are pretty simple:

> The link appears when two people are having a conversation with each other. So, you need exactly two people who have written at least three comments each (four on meta sites) within a four hour period. If a third (or fourth) person joins the discussion - then it won't trigger.
>
> That doesn't mean that any additional person on the chat thread will prevent it, only in that period of six messages.
>
> So this would trigger it (if it all happened in four hours):
>
> > Person 1, Person 2, P1, P1, P2, P2, P1
>
> But this wouldn't:
>
> > Person 1, Person 2, P1, P1, P2, Person 3, P2, P1

Person 3 acts as a combo breaker and resets the count.

"Conversation" may be a bit specific, now that I think about it - the system doesn't care whether the two people are talking to each other - they could be both giving guidance to the OP and not interacting with each other at all but still get the encouragement to move to chat.

Comment: Does the prompt show up for *both* participants in the conversation, or just the first commenter?