# Start a chat with OP before reaching the 10+ comment mark

Tags: support, comments, chat, move-to-chat

I was trying to solve someone's question and due to a language gap, they were unable to describe it properly. I know that the "let's continue this on the chat" message and link auto adds to the conversation under an answer when the comments reach 10+ in number.

I also know that [chat] is the magic link for that site's chat rooms. But it just shows the list of rooms available.

Is there a way to post/comment a "Let's continue this on chat" message and link to a user before hitting the 10+ comment mark on an answer?

Comment: Related feature request: [Should "move-to-chat" be provided on demand (as a button perhaps)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100967/335251)

Comment: The actual rules for when this appears are explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306332/how-is-the-message-please-avoid-extended-discussions-in-comments-triggered/371688#371688) - while that doesn't solve your question specifically, it might help you understand when the recommendation becomes available.

Answer (score 2):

> "Is there a way to post/comment a "Let's continue this on chat" message and link to a user before hitting the 10+ comment mark on an answer?"

Yes! First of all, that message can get suggested automatically after fewer than 10 comments (it only requires 6 comments in which two users post 3 times each without any other users commenting in between). But you can also write "Let's continue in [chat](url-to-chatroom)!" in a comment, whenever you want! The "url-to-chatroom" could be a room that already exists (to which you want to invite them), or you could create a chatroom for just that purpose. In fact we (both regular users and diamond moderators) do this all the time on Matter Modeling Stack Exchange well before the automatic suggestion is triggered, because we want to [avoid the creation of new chat rooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353643/391772).