Allow sites to customize the threshold (currently 20) for comments to trigger a flag from the Community user
When comments below a question or answer exceed 20, there is an automatic flag raised to moderators (PostTooManyCommentsAuto), which also points out that comments are not intended for extended discussions and encourages participants to take the discussion to a chatroom. (Moderators may decide to move those comments manually.)
As far as I know, the threshold of 20 applies to every Stack Exchange site, both large and small. However, some sites, or better: some users on some sites, frequently get involved in extended discussion in comments. On other sites, such discussions are very rare.
This feature request would make the threshold for the current Community♦-raised flag "x+ comments" a site-specific parameter. Moderators would then be able to request a lower threshold through a CM. (I assume this may be a feature that Stack Overflow would not want moderators to manipulate directly if it were implemented.)
The main use case I have in mind is making sure the flag can be raised on a lower number of comments, in order to reduce the number of long discussions below questions and answers.
(Indirectly related: Shog9's suggestion to rename the comment button could also be effective, based on the experiment from 2018. However, that's a different feature request.)

Interesting, this setting definitely exists for answers, but I can't find any evidence either way of a configuration for comments. See the mod team.

Perhaps something to mind: chat room retention requires at least "more than 15 messages by at least 2 users", otherwise the chat room will be deleted instead of frozen. On the sites where I mod, I've seen a few deleted chat rooms because they're prematurely moved.

The mod warning trigger probably already has a site setting but I can't confirm it. There's also definitely an existing site setting to more aggressively collapse comment sections, which is enabled on TWP and IPS at least... but it has other side effects.

Why not let users move a discussion to chat?

@Lambie Each site already has chatrooms. In many cases, they are neglected and discussions are continued in the comments.

That does not answer my question, though. I can't move a discussion to chat, right?

@Lambie "Move the discussion to chat" here means "continue the discussion in a chatroom", not "move the existing comments to a chatroom". Whether allowing high-rep users to move comments to chat is an idea that I may have seen somewhere, but I can't find where at the moment.

ELU has a link that pops up asking if you want to move "the discussion" to chat and it moves it as of the last post. I think.

@Lambie there are two separate tools. Users involved in a two-person back and forth volley of several comments within a relatively short amount of time will be given the recommendation to continue the conversation in chat, which will create a chat room with the comments that already exist but not do anything to the comments on the post. Moderators have a tool that allows them to move comments to chat (and delete them) with a comment that discourages further chatty discussion.

Here's an explanation of how the user version is triggered - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371688/284336

@Catija Yes, I know but I do not  recall seeing the user version  on FLE. And  now I see I got a comment yesterday on a related issue from seven years ago and the question was closed (don't know when) https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/656/if-comments-are-removed-completely-and-not-transferred-to-chat-is-this-fair-if?noredirect=1#comment1836_656 That kind of comment seems over the top to me.

@Lambie The closed question on French Language SE and the reason why it was closed is unrelated to this specific meta question. Let's keep the comments on topic.
